# Gostaria de saber como percorrer um array dentro de outro array em javascript!

Tags: javascript

**Boa noite**.
Estou com problema para percorrer um array dentro de outro array, eu gostaria de selecionar o usuário pela tecnologia que ele usa, no caso CSS. Se tiver como alguém me dar uma logica para eu entender e continuar meus estudos. Grato!
Segue o programa que estou fazendo, se alguém tiver dicas para melhorar, estou aprendendo ainda então desculpa qualquer erro!

```
const usuarios = [
    { nome: 'Carlos', tecnologias: ['HTML', 'CSS'] },
    { nome: 'Jasmine', tecnologias: ['JavaScript', 'CSS'] },
    { nome: 'Tuane', tecnologias: ['HTML', 'Node.js'] }
]

function users(usuarios) {
    let i = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i++) {
        console.log(`${usuarios[i].nome} trabalho com ${usuarios[i].tecnologias}.`)
    }
}

function checaSeUsuarioUsaCSS(usuario) {
    usuario.Usacss = false
    if (usuarios.tecnologias == "css"){
        usuario.Usacss = true
    }
}  

for (let i = 0; i < usuarios.length; i++) {
    const usuarioTrabalhaComCSS = checaSeUsuarioUsaCSS(usuarios[i])

    if (usuarioTrabalhaComCSS) {
        console.log(`O usuário ${usuario[i].nome} trabalha com CSS`)
    }
}

console.table(usuarios)
checaSeUsuarioUsaCSS(usuarios)
users(usuarios)
```

Comment: Só essa função `checaSeUsuarioUsaCSS()` basta para ser uma solução?

Comment: Acredito que sim, seria necessário mais? Eu modifiquei muito o programa tentando descobrir alguma solução e me perdi, no caso ali tinha um for

Comment: Eu estava preparando uma resposta, https://repl.it/repls/HideousShadySmalltalk, ma se já resolveu sua dúvida. Fazer o que? :)

Comment: Grato pela ajuda, irei olha o seu código

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu código, você está verificando se o *array* completo é uma string:

> ```
> if (usuarios.tecnologias == "css") { /* ... */ }
> ```

Isso é incorreto porque obviamente um *array* sempre será diferente da string CSS. Ademais, você não é nem capaz de comparar dois *arrays* com os mesmos valores utilizando esse operador, já que a comparação de objetos — o que inclui *arrays* — é feita por referência, diferentemente de primitivos como strings ou números.

Então, para verificar se o *array* possui um elemento que você quer procurar, utilize o método [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains). Assim você poderá verificar se a *string* `CSS`, um primitivo, está contida no *array*. Veja:

```js
function checaSeUsuarioUsaCSS(usuario) {
  return usuario.tecnologias.includes('CSS');
}

const carlos = { nome: 'Carlos', tecnologias: ['HTML', 'CSS'] };
const tuane = { nome: 'Tuane', tecnologias: ['HTML', 'Node.js'] };

console.log(checaSeUsuarioUsaCSS(carlos)); // true
console.log(checaSeUsuarioUsaCSS(tuane)); // false
```

Comment: Grato pela resposta, irei pesquisar sobre o .includes